# Javascript - storing simple higscore on server

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, server

so I have a simple JS game in which I update my variable score. 
What I would like to do on a gameOver state is to compare the score to a score that's saved on the server and if higher, overwrite it and show it and if less, show the current highscore that's saved on the server. 
I believe that it doesn't have to be stored in a database, perhaps in some php variable, but I do not know if it would be possible to update the variable via JS.
It has to do only this thing, no security or whatsoever. 
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: To transmit data to and from the server in JS, use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: Storing the highest score in a variable is not the best idea. The highest score would be reset whenever your re-start your server. Store it in a database or in json file

Comment: *"It has to do only this thing, no security or whatsoever."* So what's the point, then? At any time, the least-talented script kiddie can overwrite the high score with whatever they want.

Comment: It is just a school project so no one is going to overwrite it. @EmilS.Jørgensen, so I can get the data using Ajax, but how to write to the file and update if the highscore is higher and needs to be pushed to the server?

Comment: @Darxor That is up to the server side code. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) can save the data and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can read it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your JS is client-side and it changes nothing on the server-side.
2. Pass the score to your server using AJAX.
3. Your server-side code will do the comparison and return a result.
4. JS code on client-side will display as you expect.

You already have your game written so I assume you already know how to do AJAX in JS.
On your server YES you can use PHP to write the highest score in a file.

```
<?php
$hc = file_get_contents('YOUR_FILE_PATH');
if ( intval( $hc ) > intval( $_GET['hc'] ) ) {
    echo $hc;
} else {
    file_put_contents( $_GET['hc'], 'YOUR_FILE_PATH' );
    echo 'Congrats, your score is the highest!';
}
```